# How to work with memory like direct access files: analogues of fread and fwrite functions?

Tags: c++, memory, file-io, fwrite, fread

I need to work in my app with memory buffer like with direct access files. Is exists analogues for fread and fwrite functions? C++

I have buffer in memory with data. I want: read data, write data and move pointer in this buffer. Like files but with memory and without files.

Comment: You may want to use *pointers.*

Comment: Do not understand the question.

Comment: Please explain a little more about what you are actually trying to acheive "big picture".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean memory mapped files. It is not supported by the C++ standard, but Boost has a portable implementation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html).

Basically, it allows you to access the file through a pointer. The OS will take care of caching and, in general, it is quite efficient.

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite -- 'file-mapped memory'.

Comment: @TonyK Maybe you are right. I'm just guessing. On the other hand, is the other direction reasonable? Accessing memory via an API for files?